# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined on multiple elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of whichever button is clicked, I get error: `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`. How do I write this?

```
const activateLasers = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value)
}



const StarRating = (props) => {
    return (
     <div>
       <div onClick {this.activateLasers.bind(this)}> 
        <button value="a"> A </button>
        <button value="b"> B </button> 
        <button value="c"> C </button> 
        <button value="d"> D </button> 
        <button value="e"> E </button> 
      </div>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

Comment: this.activateLasers.bind(this) doesn't make sense. If you already can access the method using the this keyword, you don't have to bind again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div onClick={activateLasers}>
```

`activateLasers` is a plain variable that is in scope of the `StarRating` function.

`this` is usually used to refer to the current instance of a class. But there is no instance created for stateless React components, so they don't use `this`. Not to mention that `this` works very differently in arrow functions.

[Learn more about `this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine. Reference to a function activateLasers is missing. I tried creating a JSX element of your StarRating and it worked fine for me.

```
activateLasers = (event) => {
console.log(event.target.value)
}

render() {
  const test = [
    <div onClick={this.activateLasers.bind(this)}> 
     <button value="a"> A </button>
     <button value="b"> B </button> 
     <button value="c"> C </button> 
     <button value="d"> D </button> 
     <button value="e"> E </button> 
    </div>
    ];

  return(
    {test}
  );
}
```